# TypeError at Exporting CSV and Passing Data to Mail View - Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-mail

I have two problems with Queue Jobs in Laravel 9.

At one job, I'm trying to export some relational data to a .CSV file and want to notify users when exporting is finished. For this task I'm using Jobs.

This is my controller:

```
  $report = new ExportReport();
  $this->dispatch($report);
```

This is my Jobs/ExportReport.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Models\Report;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class ExportReport implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     * @return $response
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Generate our file name
        $filename="Report_Export_" . date("YmdHis") . time() . ".csv";

        // Set the file path to the temporary location
        $handler = Storage::path('public/').$filename;

        // Open file handler for writing output
        $file = fopen($handler, 'w');

        /*
         * Add headers
         */
        $headers = [
            'Inspection Number',
            'Identification of Inspection',
            'Request or Planned Date',
            'Designation of Inspection',
            'Type of Inspection',
            'Inspector Name',
            'Inspector Last Name',
            'Inspection End Date',
            'Result of Inspection',
            'Status of Inspection',
            'Reject Reason',
            'Reason of Cancellation',
            'Comments'
        ];
        fputcsv($file, $headers);

        Report::chunk(1000, function ($reports) use ($headers, $file) {
            foreach ($reports as $report) {
                fputcsv($file, [
                $report->inspection_number,
                $report->identification_of_inspection,
                $report->request_or_planned_date,
                $report->designation_of_inspection,
                $report->type_of_inspection ?? '',
                $report->employee->first_name ?? '',
                $report->employee->last_name ?? '',
                $report->inspection_end_date,
                $report->result_of_inspection->result ?? '',
                $report->status_of_inspection->status ?? '',
                $report->reject_reason->agg ?? '',
                $report->reason_of_cancellation->reason_of_cancellation ?? '',
                $report->comments ?? ''
                ]);
            }
        });

        fclose($file);

        Storage::put('public/', $file );
        Mail::to('test@mail.com')->send(new \App\Mail\ExportReport());
    }

}
```

\App\Mail\ExportReport.php

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('mails.export-report');
    }
```

**These are my problems:**

**1-** I am not able to pass any data to my mail view. I need to pass `$filename` to link the export file in mail and need to pass `auth()->user()->email` to know to which user to send.

**2-** Job exporting the file but everytime it fails with that exception message: `TypeError: League\Flysystem\Filesystem::write(): Argument #2 ($contents) must be of type string, resource given, called in...` Normally it generates the file but if I had a serious problem in fails the job, it will be impossible to trace. I have to solve this.

I am stuck and don't have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the in this way. It may help other users. I removed the line:

```
Storage::put('public/', $file );
```

Jobs/ExportReport.pdf

```
protected $user;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->user = \auth()->user();
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 * @return $response
 */
public function handle()
{

    // Generate our file name
    $filename="Report_Export_" . date("YmdHis") . time() . ".csv";

    $data = [
        'user' => $this->user,
        'filename'=>$filename,
    ];

    //dd($data);
    //dd(\auth()->user()->email);

    Mail::send('mails.export-report', $data, function ($m) use($data){
        $m->from('no-reply@mail.com', 'Sender Name');
        $m->to($this->user['email'], $this->user['first_name'].' '.$this->user['last_name'])->subject('Your export file is ready!');
    });
```